# Неэквевалентность операторов присваивания с операцией

Tags: javascript

**Почему код:**

```
var data=[1,2,3];

var i=0;

alert(data[i++]*=2);
```

**Отличается от:**

```
var data2=[1,2,3];

var b=0;

alert(data2[b++]=data2[b++]*2);
```

Comment: Наверно потому что  

    data[i++]*=2
эквивалентно  

    data[i]=data[i++]*2

а не  

    data[i++]=data[i++]*2

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае происходит следующее
по индексу 0 берется элемент, умножается на два и туда же записывается. Поэтому результат будет `[2,2,3]` и выведет 2. После выполнения операции `i = 1`.

Во втором случае, возьмется элемент по индексу 0, умножиться на 2, потом b станет равным 1. И только после этого произойдет присваивание элементу с индексом 1. Получим `[2,2,3]`. и b станет равным 2 (произойдет ещё один инкремент).

В целом, очень не рекомендуется подобные конструкции (`a[i++] = a[i++] * 2`), так как результат иногда бывает очень непредсказуем. В случае с С++ результат может быть абсолютно разным в зависимости от настроения компилятора.

Comment: спасибо,но в случае с javascript 2 и 4

Comment: Только настроение компьютера ни при чём, зависит всё строго от компилятора

Comment: Поскольку присваивание — не sequence point, два инкремента дают undefined behaviour (в C++)

Comment: @Crasher - а о настроении компьютера никто и не говорил:)

@maxim-yurewitch а у меня вывело 2 и 2. Видимо в случае JavaScript различные броузеры (используя различные версии JavaScript  могут по разному трактовать). Например у Вас alert мог просто вывести левую часть выражения. А на тот момент значение `i` и/или `b` уже могло изменится. А мог просто запомнить результат.

@VladD спасибо, КО!

Comment: IE6 видимо используете,но я уже разобрался.
Пост инкремент сначала присваивает значение,а потом увеличивает,но в первом выражении из-за выражения с операцией индекс вычисляется 1 раз.data[0]=data[0]*2=1*2=2;
Во втором же пост инкремент сначала присваивает значение,а потом увеличивает,и потом то увеличенное значение снова присваивает,и увеличивает.data[0]=data[1]*2=2*2=4;

Comment: Как же в комментарий код нормально вставить :)

Comment: так же как и в посте - 4 пробела справа

    вот 
    так

Comment: спасибо вам.

Comment: >> IE6 видимо используете
да, на линуксе, шестой... конечно.